# Printed text should appear in separate window - How?

Tags: python, tkinter, printing, module, separator

this question will be relatively simple, just do not get anywhere. It's more of a basic question.

When I write

> print ("hello world")

it appears in the script program in the message box bellow. But now I want it to open in a separate fesnter, created with tkinter. I wrote it down like this (see picture or code), but I know that print itself must not be in brackets, how can I solve this problem?

```py
from tkinter import * 

a = ("Hello World") 

root = Tk() 

T = Text(root, height=50, width=150) 

T.pack() T.insert(END, print a) 

mainloop()
```

[image: Picture with the code]

The "hello world" must appear in a separately-opened window.

I am happy about any answer.
Thanks in advance

PyBeginner

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question but can you try this one if it helps .

```
from tkinter import *
  
root = Tk() 
a = Label(root, text ="Hello World") 
a.pack() 
  
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

> Resource: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-tkinter-messagebox-widget/ Also, if you want to you can delete showinfo code and just run the w.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")

w = Label(root, text='Hello World!', font="50")
w.pack()

messagebox.showinfo("Hello World", "This is a Hello World message!!!")
root.mainloop()
```